# What is the replacement for grails.converters.deep.JSON

Tags: json, grails, serialization, deprecated

`grails.converters.deep.JSON` seems to now be deprecated. What is the replacement for:

```
import grails.converters.deep.JSON

print complexObject as JSON
```

Answer (score 7):

Looks like

```
JSON.use('deep')
```

Makes JSON converter to use eager fetching rather than lazy one, thus encode whole object graph

Answer (score 4):

use grails.converters.JSON

but add

grails.converters.json.default.deep = true

in conf/Config.goovy

See [Grails get child domain objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19144246/grails-get-child-domain-objects) for other options