# Grails get child domain objects

Tags: json, grails, grails-domain-class

I have two domain classes one is parent and other one is child and i have a hasMany relationship between them. Parent class has many childs and child class belongs to parent class.
And here is coding example.

```
class Parent{
   String name
    static hasMany = [childs:Child] 
    static constraints = {
   }
}


class Child{
   String name
   static belongsTo = [parent:Parent]
   static constraints={}
}
```

Problem is as soon as I get the parent object the child objects associated with parent class were also fetched. But when I convert the object to JSON I don't see the child object completely I can only able to see the ID's of child objects. I want to see all columns of child object instead of only Id.

Converted JSON response:

```
[{"class":"project.Parent","id":1,
  "name":"name1","childs":[{"class":"Child","id":1},{"class":"Review","id":2}]}]
```

But I want the response which contains name of child object too, as follows

```
[{"class":"project.Parent","id":1,"name":"name1",
  "childs":[{"class":"Child","id":1,"name":"childname1"},
            {"class":"Review","id":2,"name":"childname2"}
           ]
}]
```

Any help greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The issue is with the use of default JSON converter. Here are your options:

```
 1. Default  -  all fields, shallow associations
    a. render blah as JSON

 2. Global deep converter - change all JSON converters to use deep association traversal
    a. grails.converters.json.default.deep = true

 3. Named config marshaller using provided or custom converters
    a. JSON.createNamedConfig('deep'){
        it.registerObjectMarshaller( new DeepDomainClassMarshaller(...) )
    }
    b. JSON.use('deep'){
        render blah as JSON
    }

 4. Custom Class specific closure marshaller 
    a. JSON.registerObjectMarshaller(MyClass){ return map of properties}
    b. render myClassInstance as JSON

 5. Custom controller based closure to generate a map of properties
    a. convert(object){
        return map of properties
    }
    b. render convert(blah) as JSON
```

You are currently using Option 1, which is default.

The simplest you can do is use Option 2 to set global deep converter, but be aware this effects ALL domain classes in your app. Which means that if you have a large tree of associations culminating in a top level object and you try to convert a list of those top level objects the deep converter will execute all of the queries to fetch all of the associated objects and their associated objects in turn. - **You could load an entire database in one shot** :)  Be careful.

Comment: Hey Thanks I used 3rd method JSON.use('deap'){ render Parent as JSON } it just worked as I expected.

Comment: I am also having similar issue mine works only firs time then always parent class properties. I am using JSON.use('deep') then also.

Answer (score 3):

The latest grails automatically deep converts but you are probably a victim of lazy loading.

The children are not loaded at access and hence the JSON converter cannot convert them to JSON.
The workaround is to put this

static mapping = { childs lazy: false }

Comment: in grails 3.3.8 doesn't work. Childs are correctly loaded in the domain instance but once converted in JSON they still show just id

Answer (score 1):

user dbrin is correct, but there's one more option. You could also use the Grails GSON Plugin:

https://github.com/robfletcher/grails-gson#readme

The Plugin adds some more features when dealing with json data.

Answer (score 1):

The suggested solution is working, however I had some trouble referencing "grailsApplication". It turns out, that you can ingest it like any other service. I put the following code into the

> BootStrap.groovy

file. Also, the class **DeepDomainClassMarshaller** handles quite well bidirectional circular references, but beware that the JSON Payload is not to big after all deep deferencation.

```
package aisnhwr

import grails.converters.JSON
import grails.core.GrailsApplication
import org.grails.web.converters.marshaller.json.DeepDomainClassMarshaller

class BootStrap {

    GrailsApplication grailsApplication

    def init = { servletContext ->
        JSON.createNamedConfig('deep'){
            it.registerObjectMarshaller( new DeepDomainClassMarshaller(false, grailsApplication) )
        }
    }
    def destroy = {
    }
}
```