# Receiving complex json object in Grails 2.3.3

Tags: json, rest, grails, grails-domain-class

I have a similar problem to this: [Grails get child domain objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19144246/grails-get-child-domain-objects)

I'll just paste domain class code from the link for the post to be mor readable:

```
class Parent{
   String name
   static hasMany = [childs:Child] 
   static constraints = {
   }
}

class Child{
   String name
   static belongsTo = [parent:Parent]
   static constraints={}
}
```

I have created custom marshaller for Parrent object that produces something like below. 
**How do I receive and save a complex JSON object like that one ?** (I want to receive identical objects like the one that marshaller generated for me)

```
[{"class":"project.Parent","id":1,"name":"name1",
  "childs":[{"class":"Child","id":1,"name":"childname1"},
            {"class":"Review","id":2,"name":"childname2"}
           ]
}]
```

besides JSON if I had, say, all the parameters like "name" and such, the default saving code in my app is:

```
def parrent = new Parrent("parr_name") 
parrent.save()
def child = new Child("child_name", parrent)
child.save()
```

Do I have to send JSON object separately? or could I just receive complex json and drag out map of args? Does the marshaller implemented for display JSON in such manner is capable of receiving one in similar format?
I am using grails v2.3.3

Answer (score 2):

Grails 2.3.* ships with a re-defined data binding framework where you can bind a JSON payload (from a POST request in most cases) directly to the domain classes.

It works the same smart way you have tailored a marshaller for the response JSON. The way `CommandObjects` were used in earlier version of Grails it can be used likewise. Taking your own example:

```
class Parent {
    String name
    static hasMany = [children:Child]
}

class Child {
    String name
    static belongsTo = [parent:Parent]
}

//In Controller
class ParentController {

    //Directly binding the payload JSON to Parent domain class
    //Caveat here is if the corresponding Parent domain matching the id in the
    //payload is not found then "parent" parameter 
    //in the below action will be null 
    def save(Parent parent) {
        println "Parent Data $parent"
        println "Child Data $parent.children"

        render "Parent Data $parent and child data $parent.children"

        //or Do other stuff
    }
}

//Assuming you have parent and child already present
class BootStrap {
    def init = { servletContext ->
        def parent = new Parent(name: "name1")

        def child1 = new Child(name: "childname1")
        def child2 = new Child(name: "childname2")

        parent.addToChildren(child1)
        parent.addToChildren(child2)

        parent.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)
    }
}

//and payload as
POST http://localhost:8080/YourApp/parent/save
Content-Type: application/json

{"class":"project.Parent","id":1,"name":"name1",
  "childs":[{"class":"Child","id":1,"name":"childname1"},
            {"class":"Child","id":2,"name":"childname2"}
           ]
}

//curl command like
curl -X POST 
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" 
     -d '{"class":"project.Parent","id":1,"name":"name1",
          "childs":[{"class":"Child","id":1,"name":"childname1"},
                    {"class":"Child","id":2,"name":"childname2"}
                   ]
         }' 
      http://localhost:8080/YourApp/parent/save
```

You should be able to bind the JSON payload to the `Parent` domain (with children) directly. Same would be applicable if you are using url parameters instead of JSON.