# JSON serialization nested domain classes

Tags: json, mongodb, grails, grails-orm

I can't get working automatic JSON serialization nested domain classes.
The nested class is not embedded.
Grails is 2.4.3.
Only manual building map of serialized fields is working.

Marking domain fields with lazy false doesn't help.

> ```
>  class Search {
>    static mapping = {       
>           portal lazy: false
>    }
>    String id
>    Portal portal
> }
> ```

Parameter **grails.converters.json.default.deep** is also ignored

Also I tried to plugin ":marshallers:0.6".

> ```
>  class Search {
>    static marshalling = {       
>           deep 'portal'
>    }
>    String id
>    Portal portal
>  }
> ```

All fields of the nested class are presented but most of them has null values exceptional fields are class and id.

[Grails get child domain objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19144246/grails-get-child-domain-objects/)

Comment: Setting grails.converters.json.default.deep = true in `Config.groovy` didn't work for you?

Comment: Yeah. I mentioned about it.

Comment: Just clarifying because it didn't indicate you set it in `Config.groovy` but rather refer to it as `parameters`. Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: Did you try setting the deep converter explicitly in the controller, e.g. `grails.converters.JSON.use('deep')`?