# Returning a list of objects (with contents) that "belongsTo" another object in Grails

Tags: rest, grails

Currently I have set up a RESTful API to return 1 or more `Book`(s) that `belongsTo` an `Author`. Although this is what I want, it is not in the format I like it to be.

When I give an ID of 2 for the `Author`, I get the following response:

```
<author id="2">
    <author_name>Stephen</author_name>
    <books>
        <book id="2"/>
        <book id="3"/>
    </books>
</author>
```

Instead I would like a response that shows the contents of the books instead of a reference:

```
<list>
    <book id="2">
        <book_name>BookA</book_name>
        <book_year>2001</book_year>
    </book>
    <book id="3">
        <book_name>BookB</book_name>
        <book_year>2005</book_year>
    </book>
</list>
```

My contents of the controller that produces the first response is:

```
@Override
protected Book queryForResource(Serializable id) {
    def p = Author.id == params.AuthorId

    Book.where {
        id == id && p
    }.find()
}
```

Also is it possible to sort by `book_year` descending? Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are using default marshellers. Here is the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19144246/grails-get-child-domain-objects) for changing JSON response. You have to repeat this for XML. Everything else is same.

Comment: Jazakallah my friend! You are a life saver!